# if $(8a-7b-3c)^2=6(a^2-b^2-c^2)$,find $a:b:c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c>0$,and such
$$(8a-7b-3c)^2=6(a^2-b^2-c^2)$$
Find $a:b：c$

since
$$(8a-7b-3c)^2-6(a^2-b^2-c^2)=58a^2+55b^2+15c^2-112ab-48ac+42bc=0$$?

How find $a:b:c=?$

Comment: $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: No,$a,b,c$ be postive real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is homogeneous: if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then so is $(ka,kb,kc)$, so take $a=8$ and the equation becomes $3712-896b+55b^2-384c+42bc+15c^2=0$. Now put $b=7+B,c=3+C$ and we get $55B^2+42BC+15C^2=0$. We can write that as $6B^2+(7B+3C)^2+6C^2=0$, so the only real solution is $B=C=0$. Hence the solutions to the original equation are $(a,b,c)=(8k,7k,3k)$.

Of course that procedure only works because we were able to guess the solution $(8,7,3)$. How do we do that? Well if you look at the original equation it is tempting to see what happens if you put $a=8,b=7,c=3$ because then both sides have the factor $a^2-b^2-c^2$. Luckily its value is 6, so that is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put $b=a \cdot b_1$ and $c=a \cdot c_1$ into the equation you're given.
Then get rid of $a$. Then find the relation between $b_1$ and $c_1$.

That should solve your problem. The answer would then be:
$a:b:c=1:b_1:c_1$